What is the Blender equivalent to ZBrush Micromesh?
What is the Blender equivalent to ZBrush Micromesh/Nanomesh which is a type of geometry instancing?
Example:
Intro to ZBrush 046 - Use MicroMesh and NanoMesh to create complex surface detail and patterns!!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGNn1-ey6ME

What are these Micromesh Nanomesh features you mention and what do they do? Not everyone here is a ZBrush user, nor necessarily knows what that does. Could you rephrase your question and explain what you expect to achieve, and also describe with words what that feature does? Ideally in a way that doesn't reference other software so that someone who never used it but knows blender could answer your question?

Blender has an internal addon Tissue. Go to Edit > Preferences ... > Add-ons, search for tissue and enable Mesh: Tissue. Screenshot from the docs:

